# Error in plyr package in R

Tags: r

I have the following code snippet:

```
bevs <- data.frame(cbind(name = c("Bill", "Llib"), drink = c("coffee", "tea", "cocoa", "water"), cost = seq(1:8)))
bevs$cost <- as.integer(bevs$cost)

library(plyr)
count(bevs, "name")
```

Output Should be:

```
  name freq
1 Bill    4
2 Llib    4
```

But the output is :

```
count(bevs, "name")
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `"name"`     n
    <chr>  <int>
1    name      8
```

Please help.

Comment: I guess this is a package conflict. Try this: `plyr::count(bevs, 'name')` or `dplyr::count(bevs, name)`

Comment: Yes it worked. But this error has occurred recently even though I am using both plyr and dplyr package in my code for a long time. Any explanation?

Comment: You might loaded `dplyr` first?! If you load `plyr` after `dplyr` you will read "You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems. [ ... ]"

Answer (score 0):

```
bevs <- data.frame(cbind(name = c("Bill", "Llib"), drink = c("coffee", "tea", "cocoa", "water"), cost = seq(1:8)))
bevs$cost <- as.integer(bevs$cost)
```

You might want `dplyr` here

```
require(dplyr)

bevs %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(freq = n())

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  name   freq
  <fct> <int>
1 Bill      4
2 Llib      4
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not enclose the variable in quotes when `dplyr` is loaded.

```
dplyr::count(bevs, name)
```

Enclose it in quotes if using `plyr` only.

```
plyr::count(bevs, 'name')
```

You might be using `dplyr` on top of `plyr` that is why you are getting this behavior.